# How manage outer join, group_by and count with Django

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

Using Django I have the follow models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    groupPlayer = models.ForeignKey(GroupPlayer)


class GroupPlayer(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Every player is linked to a group. Some group has no player. My aim is to translate the follow query in Django (which include LEFT OUTER JOIN and Group by):

```
select GroupPlayer.description, GroupPlayer.name, COUNT(Player.name) as gplayer
from (GroupPlayer LEFT OUTER JOIN Player ON GroupPlayer.id = Player.groupPlayer_id)
GROUP BY GroupPlayer.id
```

So far I have created 3 queryset, but I cannot put them together in order to get the result I wish:

```
   queryset_player = Player.objects.values('groupPlayer_id').annotate(total=Count('groupPlayer__id'))
   queryset_group = GroupPlayer.objects.select_retated(queryset_player)
   queryset_group2 = GroupPlayer.objects.all().prefetch_related('player_set')
```

Anyone can help with that LEFT OUTER JOIN, Group by and count?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count

groups = GroupPlayer.objects.annotate(num_players=Count('player'))
groups[0].num_players
```

[Aggragation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/)